# Testing Browser Compatibility

Tags: html, css, testing, cross-browser

If I'm using Windows 7 and IE9 to test browser compatibility for css/html/javascript is it "good enough" to use the developer tools and switch the browser mode between ie7, ie8 and ie9 or should i really be testing in each stand alone version? (using a virtual machine).

Also, should i be testing these separately on XP, Vista and Win7 or will Windows 7 give me enough to test with?

I work on a Mac, and I'm trying to limit the number of virtual machines I have to run to a minimum.

Comment: You should base your decision on the users who will be visiting your website. What do they use ?

Comment: To Clarify, What I'm looking to figure out is if there is ever a visual difference in the way a page is rendered between Win7/IE8 and Win7/IE9-running in IE8 Mode - as well as other similar combinations. I want to test my site in all of them, but if i can do it all with 1 VM - then that saves me a bunch of time and effort.

Comment: Well rendering differences could exist between two given version of browser and the same version of the browser on two different OS. For the js compatibility you could use a js framework (jquery for example) but you will still have to test the css rendering. However, the differences tend to decrease with new browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...what's your baseline? IE7? One vm would do fine. I run Virtual Box for Win XP, but would suggest a stand alone machine for Win 7. I'd expect it to be a dog on a vm. But you might find it good enough. Funny thing is, FF on Linux and Win (4.0 for example) does produce different rendering results.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to test IE 7-9 - I just wasn't sure if i could eliminate the need for an XP VM yet (by replacing it with the browser modes in IE9) or if that's just asking for trouble. I'm still using other VMs to test in Linux

Comment: ... I have to do that all day at work and we just use the 'Browser Mode' in dev tools

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to test visually, I would recommend a tool like http://browsershots.org/

There are providers (such as browsercam.com) which allow you even to use Selenium scripts, to test the functionality as well (FF only though).

Comment: I've played around with a bunch of these services, but I find them slow and clunky compared to testing with the actual browsers. I just want to know what extent I need to go to get accurate results with the least number of VMs... Thanks for the suggestion though...

Answer (score 0):

You can run IETester:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

It's not perfect, and crashes, but it'll probably handle 95% of your issues if not more.

Otherwise, yes, ideally you're running each browser in their own VMs.

If you have a team that needs to do this, you could run all your browsers in server VMs and then use remote desktop as well.

MS not allowing multiple IEs to run in one windows install is near the top of my list as to why I despise MS as a web designer. ;)